# Material-UI how to get the value of SelectField inside const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

Actually, my Drawer has a few fields including SelectField but I stuck on getting the value and the onChange part of the Field. and here's my code:

```
 const DrawerCargoAddItem = (props) => {
  let { navDrawerOpen } = props;

  return (
    <Drawer docked={true} width={500} open={navDrawerOpen}>
         <div style={styles.logo}>
             Fleetcat Web
         </div>
         <div>
            <PageBase title={<Link to="dashboard"><img src="./images/fleetcat.png"/></Link>} style={page}>
                <SelectField
                   floatingLabelText="Category"
                   fullWidth={true}
                   value="">
                 <MenuItem key={0} primaryText="Food and Beverages"/>
                 <MenuItem key={1} primaryText="Medium"/>
                 <MenuItem key={2} primaryText="Large"/>
                 </SelectField>

             <Paper style={papers} zDepth={5}  >
                 <Link to="dashboard">
                     <FlatButton label="Tap to add Items" style={flatbutton}
                       onClick={() => { alert('foo');
                       console.log("Success");}}/> 
                 </Link>
             </Paper>
           </PageBase>
        </div>
    </Drawer>
  );
};

DrawerCargoAddItem.propTypes = {
  navDrawerOpen: PropTypes.bool,
  menus: PropTypes.array,
  username: PropTypes.string,
};

export default DrawerCargoAddItem;
```

Comment: Deee, are you noticing the edits I keep having to make to your posts? We like succinct posts here, and we discourage begging and pleading. It is fairly clear that you need help, so you don't need to add "please help me", "I am new to this", "I need your help guyz" etc. It's distracting and unnecessary. Would you refrain from adding this sort of thing to your future questions?

Comment: Sorry for that sir but I am just trying to please the reader and giving them the most respect that I can. Thank you for your efforts and advice. I really appreciated it all.

Comment: That's kind, but we'd rather you didn't do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a simple function and what you need is a React Component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class DrawerCargoAddItem extends React.Component {

state = {
    value: 0
};

handleChange = (event, index, value) => this.setState({value});

render() {
    let {navDrawerOpen} = this.props;
    const {value} = this.state

    return (
        <Drawer docked={true} width={500} open={navDrawerOpen}>
            <div style={styles.logo}>
                Fleetcat Web
            </div>
            <div>
                <PageBase
                    title={< Link to = "dashboard" > <img src="./images/fleetcat.png"/> < /Link>}
                    style={page}>
                    <SelectField
                        floatingLabelText="Category"
                        fullWidth={true}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <MenuItem value={0} key={0} primaryText="Food and Beverages"/>
                        <MenuItem value={1} key={1} primaryText="Medium"/>
                        <MenuItem value={2} key={2} primaryText="Large"/>
                    </SelectField>
                    <Paper style={papers} zDepth={5}>
                        <Link to="dashboard">
                            <FlatButton
                                label="Tap to add Items"
                                style={flatbutton}
                                onClick={() => {
                                alert('foo');
                                console.log("Success");
                            }}/>
                        </Link>
                    </Paper>
                </PageBase>
            </div>
        </Drawer>
    );
}
}
```

Basically you now have access to the full React lifecycle. The current value is now saved in the component's state.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```
<SelectField  floatingLabelText="Category"
     fullWidth={true}
     value=""
     onChange={this.handleChanges}>
     <MenuItem key={0} value="Food and Beverages" primaryText="Food"/>
     <MenuItem key={1} value="Medium" primaryText="Medium"/>
     <MenuItem key={2} value="Large" primaryText="Large"/>
</SelectField>
```

here is handle change event function which should be written:

```
handleChanges = (e, index, value) => {
    alert(value);
}
```

Comment: should i put it inside the const? or should I revamp my code and make a class.

Comment: There is no need to create a class as such. You can place handleChanges function after your constructor before you start with render() method and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked this syntax :  `onBlur={event => { handleChange(event) } }`

```
<Autocomplete
      id="size-small-standard"
      size="small"
      options={lOrigens}
      defaultValue={{ title: props.value }} 
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      onBlur={e => { handleChange(e, props, { setChanging: setCurrentChangingItem1, i}) }}
      renderInput={params => (
            <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="standard"
                  label="Origens1"
                  placeholder="Origens2"
                  fullWidth
            />
      )}
/>
```

And to access the value: `event.target.value`